# Make lines thicker in bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have this chart:
[image]

I have 2 issues:

1. How can I make the bars thicker and add space between them because they are so small that they blend in each other.
2. As you can see in the photo, the highest value is 3 but how can I stop the chart after that so there is no blank space like in the photo between 3 and 4.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reduce `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` properties or increase chart's height.
2. Set `yAxis.maxPadding` to `0`:

   ```
    yAxis: {
        ...,
        maxPadding: 0
    }
   ```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s3c7yz2w/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.pointPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.groupPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.height

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.maxPadding